# Positioning image behind a div with bg image

Tags: css, html, positioning, z-index, css-position

Can some one explain why I cant get the vertical bar behind my menu? I've tried absolute and relative positioning with z-indexing but no effect. Any ideas?
Live:[Test](http://www.blackflow7.nazwa.pl/test2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the body **background-image** and give to `.top` class